# How to redirect all that URLs that does not end with "feed" to https?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to redirect *all* URLs that does not end with `/feed` to a secure URL (identical, but starting with `https`), and leave all that ends with `/feed` unaltered:

I want this:

```
http://example.com/node/1234 => https://example.com/node/1234
http://example.com/blog/feed => http://example.com/blog/feed
```

Then I added the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule !^/?(.*)/feed$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

What happens is this:

```
http://example.com/node/1234 => https://example.com/node/1234
http://example.com/blog/feed => https://example.com
```

The first one is the expected result, the second is not.  Comment by *w3d* explains why this one doesn't work.

I have also tried (based on Martijn's answer):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feed$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

While I can't get this to work, I now think the problem is located elsewere and that this is the correct way to write this rule.

Comment: Why not redirect feed URLs as well?

Comment: @AndrewLott. The feed is supposed to consumed by another server (not under my control) that refuses to accept https (it seems to think the certificate is not valid). It is happy consuming http. Since I don't have direct access to this server, it has hard to debug the certificate problem. I hoped that providing it with a http-feed would be a simple solution.

Comment: `!^/?(.*)/feed$` - you cannot have a capturing subpattern in a _negated_ regex in mod_rewrite. `$1` will always be empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$` which means "Ends"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feed$
# "Ends with /feed" ------------^
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Based on your updated question, I highly doubt that's because of my code, there must be another part in your htaccess doing that. To fix the double slashes, simply remove them from the htaccess where needed, it depends on some server settings

Comment: Try taking out the slash:  `https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1` and see if that eliminates the double slash problem

Comment: Thanks for the help so far!  It looks I am experiencing some caching issues that have resulted in some confusion on my part. There may be "another part" that interferes.

Comment: Tip for FireFox: Open historybar, rightclick -> **forget** website removes cache and htaccess cache

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Martijn's answer, except using a negative-lookbehind in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* without using an additional condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?<!/feed)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Matches all URLs that do not end with `/feed`.